# php date_diff how to add up only that days hours

Tags: php, html, date, datediff

I am doing a program were you insert excel file and then you choose person and from excel it is showing when the person came in to work, and when he went out. But now I need to add up all the hour which were in the same day.
   For example the person stayed at work for 2 hours and then he left and after some time he came back and now he stayed another 5 hours and then he left again.
   So now I need that the program would recognize if the previous and next date are the same. And if they are same add them up. But the problem is how to do it and if the person says a night shift over lets say he went in at 18:00 and went out 06:00 next day. so those hours must be split. Does anyone have any ideas?

Code so far:

```css
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<?php
error_reporting(0); //disable all errors and notices
require_once "Classes/PHPExcel.php";
$chosenPerson = $_GET["dla_darbuotojo_pasirinkimas"];
$tmpfname = "visi.xls";
$excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($tmpfname);
$excelObj = $excelReader->load($tmpfname);
$worksheet = $excelObj->getSheet(0);
$lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
$aInT = "Administracija[In]";
$vInT = "Vartai[In]";
$aExT = "Administracija[Exit]";
$vExT = "Vartai[Exit]";
  
$goingIn = false;
$goingExt = false;
$diffFinall = 0;
$goingInValue = 0;
$goingExtValue = 0;

echo "<table>";
for ($row = 1; $row <= $lastRow; $row++) {
    if ($chosenPerson ==  ($worksheet->getCell('D'.$row)->getValue()) ) {
        if (!$goingIn or !$goingExt) {
            //checking if the person alredy went in
            if ((($worksheet->getCell('G'.$row)->getValue()) == $aInT) or (($worksheet->getCell('G'.$row)->getValue()) == $vInT)) {
                //if the person went in
                $goingIn = true;
                echo "<tr><td>";
          $goingInValue = $worksheet->getCell('F'.$row)->getValue();
          echo $worksheet->getCell('D'.$row)->getValue();
          echo "</td><td>";
          echo $worksheet->getCell('F'.$row)->getValue();
          echo "</td><td>";
          echo $worksheet->getCell('G'.$row)->getValue();
          echo "</td><td>";
      
          for ($erow= $row +1; ; $erow++){
                    if ($chosenPerson ==  ($worksheet->getCell('D'.$erow)->getValue()) ) {
                        if ((($worksheet->getCell('G'.$erow)->getValue()) == $aExT) or (($worksheet->getCell('G'.$erow)->getValue()) == $vExT)) {
                            $goingExtValue = $worksheet->getCell('F'.$erow)->getValue();
         $goingExt=true;
         
         echo $worksheet->getCell('D'.$erow)->getValue();
         echo "</td><td>";
         echo $worksheet->getCell('F'.$erow)->getValue();
         echo "</td><td>";
         echo $worksheet->getCell('G'.$erow)->getValue();
         echo "</td><td>";
         
         $date1=date_create($goingInValue);
         $date2=date_create($goingExtValue);
         $diff=date_diff($date2,$date1);
         echo $diff->format("%h Val %i Min %s Sek");
         $diffFinall= $diffFinall + $diff;
         echo "</td><tr>";
         $goingIn = false;
         $goingExt = false;
         break;
         $row=$erow;
        }
       }       
      }
     } 
    }
    
    
    //echo "<tr><td>";
    //echo $worksheet->getCell('D'.$row)->getValue();
    //echo "</td><td>";
    //echo $worksheet->getCell('F'.$row)->getValue();
    //echo "</td><td>";
    //echo $worksheet->getCell('G'.$row)->getValue();
    //echo "</td><tr>";
   }
  }
  echo "<tr><td>";
  echo "Viso:";
  echo $diffFinall;
  echo "</td></tr>";
  echo "</table>";
  

?>
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Every people in and out you save to database right? Before you insert, you can check it's exist with same people in same date, if yes, you can sum total hours or insert row and select and sum it. And if night shift, you need flag in your DB for it's so you can condition when night shift

Comment: not storing in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is quite long and I don't have the data to test it. So I made a snippet that basically covers the logic you should be using.

```
// Define total hours before.
$totalHours = 0;

// Imaginary loop {

/**
 *  B and E are th columns 
 *  should be replaced with $worksheet->getCell('B'.$erow)->getValue()
*/
$B = '2018-12-04 07:44:56';
$E = '2018-12-04 18:52:31';

$B = strtotime($B);
$E = strtotime($E);

// this total hours could be part of a multi dimensional array
// it keeps adding up because of this: +=
$totalHours += ($E-$B)/60/60;

// } End Imaginary Loop

echo $totalHours;
```

You could name it multi dimensional with using `$chosenPerson` as a key in your array. Something like this:

```
$totalHours = array();

// in the loop:
if (!isset($totalHours[$chosenPerson]))
    $totalHours[$chosenPerson] = ($E-$B)/60/60;
else
    $totalHours[$chosenPerson] += ($E-$B)/60/60;
// end of loop

var_dump($totalHours);
```

Comment: why are you dividing ($E-$B)/60/60; ?

Comment: `strtotime` function gives a time stamp in seconds. So we want hours, therefor we divide by 60 for the minutes and another 60 for the hours.